# Skip multiple lines lines ANTLR 4

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I need to parse a file with service information and table. The main values should be retrieved only from the table.

Please advice how can we start parsing only from "==========" or maybe I can skip the service info before the table? The problem is that service info can be up to 50+ lines and it will not be possible to write pattern for each of it.

```
180401-14:50:33 18.XXX.XX.XX 19.0n  stopfile=/tmp/156
Checking MOM version...RBS_NSHELFE_MODEL_UK_434_51
Parsing MOM (cached): /var/opt/ericsson/amos/moshell_logfiles/fitofs/logs_moshell/tempfiles/20180405-145440_75/RBS_NODE_MODEL_U_4_591.xml.cache.gz ....................................................................Done.
Using paramfile /opt/amos/moshell/commonjars/pm/PARAM_RBS_908.txt
Parsing file /opt/amos/moshell/commonjars/pm/PARAM_RBS_908.txt ..............................................................................................Done.
Fetching IOR file...Done.
Connecting to 10.XXX.2XX.XX:45678 (CorbaSecurity=ON, java=1.7.0_51, DFACOM=R89IKW, DFACOB=R45RT)
**** Welcome to the Simple Mo Browser (version 3.0)!
Trying file=/var/optamos/moshell_logfiles/tempfiles/20180305-145990_75/YU66
**** Test Construction OK
****

$mobrowser_pid = 908

Connected to 17.XXX.XXX.XX (SubNetwork=ONRM_WE_OKL_O,SubNetwork=WSX987,ManagedElement=100)
Last KO:  1209. Loaded 1209 KOs. Total:  1221KOs.

Checking available shelfs...

Collecting SPEED wifi data...
.......

Collecting CPU shelf data...

Created following board-groups: all, wer, ik, pl, sd, boardf, wsyu8, vse, fcv, hnj, sccpmp, et, etmfg, etmfx, qw34df, dfr, qw56df, aal8uj, xp, trx, rx, tem, su[1-8].
Type "bp" to view available board-groups and "bp <group>" to view group contents.

Collecting tpm data...
..........
Collecting UF data...
put /var/opt/amos/moshell_logfiles/tempfiles/20180305-148840_75/R/d/usr/TY6HGNB88AZe345O  ... OK
..............................................................................................................................................

PART: IB10203T    DOM_OO_BACKPLANE CTU09098787/8_QW90TY6 U17I2.P ()

=====================================================
TPM LED  BOARD    LOCATION  U  ACTION STATE CIRCLE CREACJ   R/p   Y  PRODUCTNUMBER  ROI   SERIAL     DATE     KO
=====================================================
  0   1  KKK4101  Main_TOP      2  ON   OFF   OFF   ON     0% 18%  TRY105557/4    R44/A TURT5683 20160228 1,Slot=5  (1100/1100 BJ)
=====================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be done with a non-greedy lexer rule:

```
SERVICE_INFO : .*? '==========' -> skip;
```

Comment: Hi @JiriTousek, thanks for the reply. but unfortunately the solution does not cover the empty lines [ \n\r ].

Comment: have you tried adding them explicitly? `(.|\r|\n)*?`

Answer (score 0):

One Way to achieve that is to resort to a feature of antlr called [islands grammars](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ANTLR3/pages/2687313/Island+Grammars+Under+Parser+Control) . In short: to use them you have to, practically, identify a start token and a stop token such that you can switch lexical modes.

Comment: Hi @gtosto thanks for suggestion, but cannot be used for my case as fist line can be changed dynamically.